# difference in giving parameters to opengl code in LWJGL and PyOpenGL

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, pyopengl

i am learning opengl with python.and following this course
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WMiggUPst-Q&list=PLRIWtICgwaX0u7Rf9zkZhLoLuZVfUksDP&index=2
just to be able to do.he is using LWJGL, i am PyOpengl. i noticed some of his methods (`glgenVertexArray`, `gldeleteVertexArray` ...ex) is used without parameters even docs says otherwise. while i wrote same code in python it's says

> glGenVertexArrays requires 1 arguments (n, arrays), received 0: ()

it' wants a parameter from me for the same method. it's not a problem here(i think) give 1 but when its come to `glDeleteVertexArrays` if i dont give 1 and the list that i am keeping vao,vbo ids its raises this

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\TheUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\latebind.py", line 43, in **call**
> return self._finalCall( *args, **named )
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
>
> > During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > File "C:/Users/TheUser/Desktop/MyPytonDen/ThinMatrixOpenGl/engineTester/MainGameLoop.py", line 22, in 
> > Loader.CleanUP()
> > File "C:\Users\TheUser\Desktop\MyPytonDen\ThinMatrixOpenGl\renderEngine\Loader.py", line 12, in CleanUP
> > glDeleteVertexArrays()
> > File "C:\Users\TheUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\latebind.py", line 47, in **call**
> > return self._finalCall( *args, **named )
> > File "C:\Users\TheUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\wrapper.py", line 689, in wrapperCall
> > pyArgs = tuple( calculate_pyArgs( args ))
> > File "C:\Users\TheUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\wrapper.py", line 436, in calculate_pyArgs
> > raise ValueError(
> > ValueError: glDeleteVertexArrays requires 2 arguments (n, arrays), received 0: ()

i handle this as i say but i dont think its appropriate.
so i am asking what its acctuly want from me (docs wasn't explicit enough for me) and why it's wants for PyOpenGl but not LWJGL

and this is the file:

```
from ThinMatrixOpenGl.renderEngine.RawModel import RawModel
from OpenGL.GL import *
import numpy as np

VAOs = []
VBOs = []

def CleanUP():
     print(VAOs, VBOs)
     for vao in VAOs:
     glDeleteVertexArrays(int(vao), VAOs)

for vbo in VBOs:
     glDeleteBuffers(int(vbo), VBOs)

def LoadToVao(positions):
     global VAOs
     VAO_ID = CreateVao()
     VAOs.append(VAO_ID)
     storeDataInAttribList(0, positions)
     unbindVao()
     return RawModel(vao_id=VAO_ID, vertex_count=(len(positions) / 3))

def CreateVao():
     VAO_ID = glGenVertexArrays(1)
     glBindVertexArray(VAO_ID)
     return VAO_ID

def storeDataInAttribList(attrib_number: int, data: float):
     global VBOs
     VBO_id = glGenBuffers(1)
     VBOs.append(VBO_id)
     glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_id)
     buffer = StoreDataInFloatBuffer(data)
     glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
     glVertexAttribPointer(attrib_number, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, None)
     glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)

def unbindVao():
     glBindVertexArray(0)

def StoreDataInFloatBuffer(data: float):
     buffer = np.array(data, dtype=np.float32)
     return buffer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification - 10.3.1 Vertex Array Objects](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#page=371&zoom=100,168,600)

> ```
> void DeleteVertexArrays( sizei n, const uint *arrays );
> ```

See PyOpneGL - `glDeleteVertexArrays`:

> Signature
>
> ```
> glDeleteVertexArrays( GLsizei ( n ) , const GLuint *( arrays ) )-> void
>    def glDeleteVertexArrays( n , arrays )
> ```

The 2nd argument must be an array with the element type "unit":

```py
def CleanUP():
     np_vaos = np.array([vao], dtype="uint")
     glDeleteVertexArrays(np_vaos.size, np_vaos)
```

In newer PyOpenGL versions, however, the second argument can also be a list:

```py
def CleanUP():
    glDeleteVertexArrays(len(VAOs), VAOs)
```

When using LWJGL, the size argument (*n*) is deduced from the Java array object. Different libraries in different languages provide different overloads for the OpenGL API functions. If a function behaves unexpectedly and differs from the OpenGL specification, you must consult the API documentation for the libraries.

Comment: Thank you! so its upto apis own implementation. i asume same true for genbuffer and deletebuffers

Comment: @AAAA Yes. See [PyOpenGL - `glGenBuffers`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glGenBuffers.html) and [PyOpenGL -`glDeleteBuffers`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glDeleteBuffers.html)